# Selecting single row if it matches another

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a scenario of this type:

[image]

I want to select only one row in such a scenario. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any primary key in this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `distinct on` with `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select distinct on (least(name1, name2), greatest(name1, name2)) t.*
from mytable t
order by least(name1, name2), greatest(name1, name2), name1
```

An alternative is `not exists`:

```
select *
from mytable 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.name1 = t.name2 and t1.name2 = t.name1 and t1.name1 < t1.name2
)
```

Finally: if *all* of the rows are duplicated, then a simple `where` condition is sufficient:

```
select *
from mytable
where name1 < name2
```